# kendoui mobile listview become unclickable if grouped listview has template with <a href=""> + switch

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, listview, switch-statement, kendo-ui

**Hi all,**

I just new in kendo ui and you may consider my question silly, but still I need to get an answer.

All code is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/Oleksii/vvCHX/27/

In my scenario I have mobile application with 2 views:

- defaultView (id="") contains 2 list view: one statically defined; the second one is initialized in view init event handler); This non-static listview has template called "fileGroupsItemTemplate".
- second view has no content (id="aboutView").

Non-static view's item MUST:

1. be clickable (I mean Link Items) to get ability to navigate to other view;
2. have switch on the right side in every row
3. View MUST be chnaged only if switch is checked
   I faced with the problems: if I click on switch it changes its value, but current view is changed too.

It is because switch is inside  tag (see template). But if I put it out of  tag,

1. items are shown as a link;
2. items become unclickable;
3. if I click the link, then will get an error:

> {"error": "Please use POST request"}
>   
>   Does anyone know how to prevent changing view after clicking on switch inside  tag? I was thinking about some trick in event handlers, but item-click event of list view is raised in the first place, and switch-change just after.

**Here is template:**

```
<script id="fileGroupsItemTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <img src="#= data.Image#" />
    </td><td style="vertical-align: middle">
        #= data.Name #
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
#if(data.Docs.length > 0){#
<ul>
    #for(var i=0; i < data.Docs.length; i++){#
    <li>
        <a >#=data.Docs[i].Name#
        <input data-on-label="Cl" data-off-label="Sk" data-role="switch" #=data.Docs[i].NeedProcess ? "checked='checked'" : ""# /></a>

    </li>
    #}#
</ul>
#}#
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that via your [forum thread here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mobile/listview/mobile-listview-become-unclickable-if-grouped-listview-has-template-with-a-href-switch.aspx) (I assume this is you), this is not yet a supported scenario, BUT...

You can pull it off with some creativity keeping in mind that you are really circumventing the way the ListView is supposed to work and therefore you may or may not get some fringe anomalies that you have to deal with.

Here is the completed solution...

http://jsfiddle.net/vvCHX/30/

A few things of note:

1. I updated your script references to the latest version of Kendo UI (2012.3.1114)
2. Instead of using a ListView and populating it with other ListViews, I changed it so your DataSource appends the template to the DOM when the DataSource is read via the **change** event.
3. As was stated in the forum thread, you cannot nest an input inside of an anchor because that is by definition malformed HTML.  What you can do instead is use a span tag and give it the same classes that the anchor gets.  You listen to the click event and check the e.target of the event.  If it's the list item, then you can navigate to the next view.  If it isn't, then you do nothing and just let the switch do its thang.

So now the **initFileGroupsList** function looks just so:

```
function initFileGroupsList(e) {
  // compile the template    
  var template = kendo.template($("#fileGroupsItemTemplate").html());

  // create a new datasource
  var fileGropsRemoteDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{"__type":"JsonFileTypeGroup:#" .... }],
    change: function() {

      // the 'change' function is called when the datasource reads

      // replace the 'dynamic' plaholder div with the output of the template
      $("#dynamic").replaceWith(kendo.render(template, this.view()));

      // create the listview widgets
      $(".listview").kendoMobileListView({
        style: "inset",
        click: function(e) {
          // when the listview is clicked, get the item that was actually 
          // clicked in the DOM and wrap it in jqueries
          var item = $(e.target);

          // if the item has the 'clickable' class..
          if (item.hasClass("clickable")) {
            // set its style to highlight the item blue
            item.addClass("km-state-active");

            // navigate to the next view
             app.navigate("#aboutView");        
          }
        }
      });
    $(".switch").kendoMobileSwitch();
  }
});
```